# How to display a number close to zero in c#?

Tags: c#, string, double

I have a problem. I have a double number like 0.00000001. Then I should convert it into String and put it in textbox (Convert.ToString(0.00000001)). But that number displayed like 1E-08. Math.Round is not working here. I should display that number like 0.00000 (at least), not just 0.

Comment: Add an `m` suffix after the number. `Convert.ToString(0.0000001m)`

Comment: num.ToString("N5")  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [The numeric `("N")` format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#NFormatString) for that;

```
(0.00000001).ToString("N5").Dump(); // 0,00000
(0.00000001).ToString("N6").Dump(); // 0,000000
(0.00000001).ToString("N8").Dump(); // 0,00000001
```

Since my [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture(v=vs.110).aspx)'s [`NumberDecimalSeparator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.numberdecimalseparator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is `,`, it represents it as `0,0` not `0.0`. If it is the same for you, you can use [`InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture(v=vs.110).aspx) as a second parameter in your `.ToString()` method.